# Cannot open NetCDF file with QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, netcdf, mesh, wrf-model

I have a problem regarding the NetCDF files downloaded from this site: https://map.neweuropeanwindatlas.eu/

Every time I try to open any of the files using QGIS "Layer > Add Layer > Add Mesh Layer" I get this error:

[image]

I'm using QGIS version 3.20.1

Does that mean there is something wrong with this file or there is some other way to open NetCDF files?

The downloaded NetCDF file seems to bo be wrf-netcdf file which differs from regular netcdf, more info here: https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/wrfnetcdf.shtml

I've found the QGIS plugin called gis4wrf, however due to error which I have no idea how to fix ("Couldn't load plugin 'gis4wrf' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method".), I can't install it.

Comment: How would you get the nc file? I just gave a look into the portal and saw the formats are JSON and CSV? did you tried checking other NetCDF files???

Comment: @YogeshChavan Draw an area and in the top right corner switch from "Plots" to "Meso Download" tab. There choose the date and parameter and hit download.